# How to replace the given email address with a value in a given input?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have written the method shown below to replace some of the email domains like `@gmail.com` and `@yahoo.com` with a given text:

```
public static string RemovePersonalInfo(string input)
{
    string[] tokens = input.Split(new char[] { ' ', '\t', '\r', '\n' });
    string output = string.Empty;

    foreach (string token in tokens)
    {
        if (token.Contains("@gmail.com"))
        {
            output += " SOMETEXT";
        }
        else
        {
            output += " " + token;
        }
    }

    tokens = output.Split(new char[] { ' ', '\t', '\r', '\n' });
    output = string.Empty;

    foreach (string token in tokens)
    {
        if (token.Contains("@yahoo.com"))
        {
            output += " SOMETEXT";
        }
        else
        {
            output += " " + token;
        }
    }

    return output;
}
```

It is working as expected for the below input.

But I don't think it is a good solution, I can see the improvements in the code but it is not scalable, let's see tomorrow some other email domain comes, I will have to again modify the code and write another if condition. the second improvement is that I am running the loop twice, it can be done in one loop. so performance can be improved.

Or if there is any better approach than this, please suggest.

Input:

```
test@gmail.com   test@abc.com   @teest@yahoo.com
```

Output:

```
SOMETEXT   test@abc.com   SOMETEXT
```

**Note**: I am not supposed to use the Replace method. So the only intention here is to use the same logic in basic programming languages like C and C++ as well.

Comment: Seems like the sort of place I'd use a Dictionary to map `@yahoo.com` -> `SOMETEXT`

Comment: @CaiusJard I think adding to the config file will be better than using dictionary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you @Caius, your answer helped me really.

I have also tried the below ways to solve the issue. I have hardcoded the values in my example, but these can be configured.

```
public static string RemovePersonalInfo(string input)
{
    if (input == null) { throw new NullReferenceException(nameof(input)); }
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(input)) { return input; }

    return RemovePersonalInfo(input.Split(new char[] { ' ', '\t', '\r', '\n' }), new string[] { "@gmail.com", "@yahoo.com" });

}
private static string RemovePersonalInfo(IEnumerable<string> tokens, IEnumerable<string> domains, string replacement = "SOMETEXT")
{
    return string.Join(" ", tokens.Select(token => (domains.Any(domain => token.Contains(domain)) ? replacement : token)));
}

public static string RemovePersonalInfoUsingRegex(string input)
{
    //Regex and SOMETEXT can come from the configurartion
    return Regex.Replace(input, @"(?<=\s+|^)(\S+(@gmail.com|@yahoo.com))(?=\s+|$)", "SOMETEXT", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To expand on my comment, I came to realize that there isn't really much point using a Dictionary because you don't need any of the functionality it provides. All you really need is a list of find replace pairs:

```
public static string RemovePersonalInfo(string input)
{
    //this is just hardcoded for purposes of the question. Consider putting it in config file or DB etc. 
    //It's simply a list of Find/Replace pairs

    (string F, string R)[] frs = { 
      ( "@yahoo.com", "SOMETEXT" ), 
      ( "@gmail.com", "SOMEOTHERTEXTMAYBE" ) 
    };

    string[] tokens = input.Split(' ', '\t', '\r', '\n');

    var outputSb = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (string token in tokens) {
      var fr = frs.FirstOrDefault(t => token.Contains(t.F));
      outputSb.Append(" ").Append(fr == default ? token : fr.R);
    }
   
    return outputSb.ToString();
}
```

The actual pairs can come from config, DB, code etc..

If SOMETEXT will always be the same, you can just use a simple enumerable of string:

```
public static string RemovePersonalInfo(string input, string sometext)
{
    //this is just hardcoded for purposes of the question. Consider putting it in config file or DB etc
    var ws = new[]{"@yahoo.com","@gmail.com"};

    string[] tokens = input.Split(' ', '\t', '\r', '\n');

    var outputSb = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (string token in tokens) 
      outputSb.Append(" ").Append(ws.Any(w => token.Contains(w)) ? sometext : token);


    return outputSb.ToString();
}
```

If the output is not supposed to have a leading space, use `outputSb.ToString(1, sb.Length-1)`

Comment: What if input string is null, we can also move the delimiter config file? I think it’s can be optimised if any token is repeated in the string

Comment: @Andrw yes, if I was enumerating KVPs.. And i think the original code outputted a leading space, no? (And you'd just use the overload of ToString(int, int) on the sb, you wouldn't make 2 strings?)

Comment: Yes, the original also has the leading space, but I highly doubt it's something done on purpose.

Comment: @viveknuna *What if input string is null* - put some handling in for that case? Your original question didn't state that it would be, nor had code to handle it. *I think it’s can be optimised if any token is repeated in the string* - but you specifically didn't want to use Replace to hit all the tokens in one pass; you wanted to tokenize the string and then examine each one. I suspect the performance will be broadly the same anyway

Comment: I responded to that: *yes, if I was enumerating KVPs*

Comment: Sorry, but I don't know what that is supposed to answer; I just suggested improvements. `== default` is still unnecessary to me. If `Any()` is true, you need `sometext`, not `token`. Finally, as in my comment, `Substring(1)` is enough, no need for `sb.Length-1`.

Comment: @CaiusJard I have upvoted your answer. Thank you for your help and time